# operator << of enum type uses the overloaded operator or not?

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I hope this time my question is better formulated and formatted.
Here's the code that produces two separate outputs when I think it should not since I use everytime (I think) the overloaded operator<< for an enum type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Etat { Intact = 5 };

class Ship {

public: 
Etat etat_;  

Ship ( Etat t = Intact) : etat_(t) {}
~ Ship() {} 

ostream& description ( ) const {  return cout <<  "Etat: " << etat_ << "   ---   ";} 
//---------------------------------------ˆˆˆˆ----
};

ostream& operator<< ( ostream& s, const Etat& etat_ ) 
{
  switch  ( etat_ )
    {
      case Intact:    s << "intact";   break;
      default:        s << "unknown state";
    }
  return s;
}

ostream& operator<< ( ostream& s, Ship n )  {  return s <<  "Etat: "  <<  n.etat_ ; }

int main()
{
  Etat etat_ = Intact;   
  cout << endl << endl << "Etat: " 
       << etat_ << "       \"cout << etat_\"" << endl << endl;

  cout << Ship(etat_) 
       << "       \"cout << Ship(etat_)\"" << endl << endl;

  cout << Ship(etat_).description() 
       << "  \"cout << Ship(etat_).description()\"" << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is what I get in the terminal:

```
Etat: intact       "cout << etat_"

Etat: intact       "cout << Ship(etat_)"

Etat: 5   ---   1  "cout << Ship(etat_).description()"
```

Can anyone explain to me why, in the last case, not only it takes the integer value of the enum attribut, but also adds a "1" after the test string "  ---  "???

The only thing I can think of is because I used an unorthodox return method in description(), ie 'return cout << ..", but it seems to work since the test string appears.

Is there a way to force the use of the operator<< overload in description()?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the description() function you are returning a reference to std::cout and use it in the std::cout call in main function. There is a reason why operator<< takes an ostream reference as it's first argument. You should modify your function like this and all should work:

```
ostream& description(ostream& os) const {  
    return os <<  "Etat: " << etat_ << "   ---   ";
}
```

The random "1" printed out there is caused likely due to the ostream in your example trying to print out reference to itself.